# How can add additional information to a JavaScript MouseEvent, for example, a relativeClientX property?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I may need the `clientX` and `clientY` of `MouseEvent`, so `MouseEvent` is enough. But other times, I may need `clientRelativeX` and `clientRelativeY` calculated using `getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
/**
 * @param {function(MouseEvent, HTMLElement): void} onMouseMove
 * @param {HTMLElement} [document] targetElement
 */
export const registerMouseMoveHandler = (onMouseMove, targetElement = document) => {
  targetElement.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const {
      left: leftOffset,
      top: topOffset,
    } = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    const clientRelativeX = e.clientX - Math.floor(leftOffset);
    const clientRelativeY = e.clientY - Math.floor(topOffset);

    // Maybe e.clientRelativeX = clientRelativeX;
    // Maybe e.clientRelativeY = clientRelativeY;
    
    onMouseMove(e, targetElement);
  });
};
```

So my question is: should I add properties directly to the `MouseEvent`? Is supported by all major browser or it's a non-standard way of doing this? Another possibility would be a `CustomEvent` with an originalEvent property.

Comment: I doubt there's a browser that would give you trouble if you added the properties to the existing event object, but as a matter of opinion, I'd very much go with the `CustomEvent` approach.

Comment: So you would capture the original event and add another event listener for a CustomEvent with the added properties?

Comment: It's hard to say with out more context. I'm not sure why you'd need to register another handler, aren't you just calling `onMouseMove`? (At first i thought you were providing an API, now I'm not sure what context this is running in.)

Comment: It's just an helper function. But AFAIK I need to dispatch my `CustomEvent`, just from inside the `mousemove` handler (copying properties of the original event + adding more properties). Then I need to listen to my `CustomEvent` and call `onMouseMove`?

Comment: You can just pass the event object to `onMouseMove`, you don't have to dispatch it.